# How to write nginx redirect rule for mapping all unmatched urls to one rule

Tags: redirect, nginx

Here is my initial nginx rule :

```
location /main/ {
  root /app/dist;
  try_files $uri /index.html =404;
}
```

however, I want redirect all the urls which are not `/main/` to `/main/`, even include the root url path `/`

How should I add nginx redirect rule ?